# Angular - Horizontal Scroll problem while dragging items with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a horizontal scroller for images in Angular, but it has to scroll left-right while dragging images left or right with mouse. I have written following code in component's TS file:

```
@ViewChild('container', { static: true }) container: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('images', { static: true }) images: ElementRef;

  isDragging = false;
  startPosition = 0;
  scrollLeft = 0;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const container = this.container.nativeElement;
    const images = this.images.nativeElement;
    let initialTranslateX = 0;

    // MOUSE:
    container.addEventListener('mousedown', (e: MouseEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.isDragging = true;
      this.startPosition = e.clientX - initialTranslateX;
      container.style.cursor = 'grabbing';

      console.log(initialTranslateX)
    }, true);

    container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!this.isDragging) return;

      const x = e.clientX - this.startPosition;
      const newTranslateX = initialTranslateX + x;

      console.log(newTranslateX);

      this.setTranslateX(images, newTranslateX);
    }, true);

    container.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      this.isDragging = false;
      container.style.cursor = 'grab';
      initialTranslateX = this.getTranslateX(images);

    }, true);

    container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      this.isDragging = false;
      container.style.cursor = 'grab';
      initialTranslateX = this.getTranslateX(images);
    }, true);
}

setTranslateX(images, translateX: number) {
    images.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px)`;
  }

  getTranslateX(images): number {
    const transformValue = window.getComputedStyle(images).transform;
    const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(transformValue);
    return matrix.m41;
  }
```

Following code block in component's HTML file:

```
<div class="image-container" #container>
    <div class="images" #images fxLayout="row">
      <img [src]="image.imageURL" *ngFor="let image of animationItemsList" style="width: 900px;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And following code in component's CSS file:

```
.image-container {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

The problem is that, first time when I do a scroll while dragging items, it works just fine, but after the first time, it really starts misbehaving. #images div is jumping left and right each time I try to scroll after the first time.

I was debugging the code and trying to find a mistake in calculating values for translateX property, but I didn't manage to find a mistake.